# Excel does not fully open when starting macro on Workbook_Open

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a makro that I want to run directly when the workbook is opened. It works, however, the macro starts before the real spreadsheet opens completely, and I only see the Excel splash the entire time the makro runs.

I should mention that I open the workbook through the Windows Task Scheduler. Once the file is opened, the macro go through a loop and open a list of other Excel files that are updating external data using the SAP Analysis plugin.

I call the spreadsheet with the macro as a scheduled task to update data and then close it again automatically:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Range("start_on_open").value = "YES" Then
        Call Process_action_table
    End If
End Sub
```

`start_open` is a named range in my sheet, and when I set it to "YES", the makro will start automatically.

While the function "Process_action_table" is running, I display status information in the spreadsheet, but of course with only the splash screen visible, nothing is really displayed.

When I run the macro "manually", everything works fine. It seems to me that it is somehow as if there was not enough processing time left to open the spreadsheet properly.

I have added the following code at the start, but to no avail:

```
t_end = Now + TimeValue("0:0:10")
Do While Now < t_end
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

divingTobi. If worksheet loading is indispensable condition instead of using `Workbook_Open()` utilization of `Worksheet_Activate()` is suitable. Try to paste this code to worksheet which contains "start_on_open" range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Range("start_on_open").value = "YES" Then
        Call Process_action_table
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, this only works when I click on the workbook after the file has  opened, but not automatically when the file is loaded...

Comment: It works when I open the file manually, but when I open it from the Windows scheduler, it does not open, even when I add "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(___).Select" to the Workbook.Open function.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I open the file from the Windows Task Scheduler. I get the same result when calling it directly from the command line: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"  path_to_excel.xlsx`.

Comment: Could you provide detailed explanation about opening file from scheduler? What exactly you doing to launch file automatically?

Comment: In the scheduler the action is: "Start a Program", with Program: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE", and argument "path_to_excel.xslx". You can simulate it by calling Excel from the command line as mentioned above. The main file will not show either, even though the macro starts running.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this code. Please give feedback if it is good or not.
It will loop/wait for workbook to be writeable.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    If Range("start_on_open").value = "YES" Then
        'wait for workbook to writeable
        Do Until wb.ReadOnly = False
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        Loop
        Call Process_action_table
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, no, does not work either unfortunately. The macro starts, but now I do not even see the splash screen anymore.